nginx conf for blocking direct IP
We have an email server running on a Ubuntu 22.04 with nginx. I am quite new to nginx and try to configure the 00-default.conf in sites-enabled to block requests that come direct from an IP address and not from a domain. Using code 444. The nginx is version 1.18
How can I do this. I have read various tutorials on the net but all have different approaches
Our server for the moment has 5 maildomains setup

you are better off asking this on a nginx or webservers related site. this will work: https://www.codedodle.com/disable-direct-ip-access-nginx.html  Mind that methods listing nginx 1.19 do not work. The 444 response is ONLY for HTTP. For HTTPS you need a self signed cert.
